# Can multiple inputs be passed as array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use a base list as shown below and pass the parameters for action column in order to create-edit-delete actions. However, as the actions vary from table to another table, I want to send them as array, etc. and do not create unnecessary property name on the base table. So, how can I perform it?

***base-list.html:***

```
<td>
    <button (click)="emitFirst(event)"></button>
    <button (click)="emitSecond(event)"></button>
    <button (click)="emitThird(event)"></button>
</td>
```

***base-list.ts:***

```
@Output() first: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Output() second: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Output() third: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

emitFirst(data) {
    this.first.emit(row);
}

emitSecond(data) {
    this.second.emit(data);
}

emitThird(data) {
    this.third.emit(data);
}
```

***employee-list.html:***

```
<base-list
    (first)="create($event)"
    (second)="edit($event)"
    (third)="delete($event)"
>
</base-list>
```

Comment: so you want to pass only 1 output parameter to child component instead of 3 . If yes how would you like to know which button has been pressed?

Comment: I think to use the array order. But I have no idea, is the approach above is the only way that can be used for this scenario? I am really confused. But adding max number of input and emitters to the base component is not seems to be good I think. Any idea?

Comment: The event binding doesn't assign or call if you provide a field.

Comment: Thanks, but what would you suggest for this scenario?

Comment: Add a single output in base and handle same in parent. However while emitting the value. also pass the click button information so that you can distinguish which button is click in your parent component.

Answer (score 1):

In your Base Component add a single output like below:-

```
export class BaseComponent {
  @Output() actions: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  emitFirst(data) {
    this.actions.emit({"button":"first",data:'hello'});
  }

  emitSecond(data) {
    this.actions.emit({"button":"second",data:'hello'});
  }

  emitThird(data) {
    this.actions.emit({"button":"third",data:'hello'});
  }
}
```

And in your parent consume it like below:-

```
<app-base (actions)="clicked($event)"> </app-base>
```

In your response you will get an object as an output where the first parameter will explain which button has been clicked. Based on that type you can perform your actions.

```
{button: "first", data: "hello"}
{button: "second", data: "hello"}
```

Here is the link of a codeSandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/ng-multiple-output-tkmmx

Instead of handling if else condition for getting which button is clicked you can use lookup approach like below in your parent component.
Here you are creating an object with list of button type as key and corresponding function name as value. When you get the button click handler in your parent then just use this lookup event by the key and invoke the method which is passed as the value.
Going forward if there is new type comes up then just add that button type and function in your lookup object, no other code needs to be touched.

```
  lookEvents = {
    [ButtonType.FIRST]: this.invokeFirstCall,
    [ButtonType.SECOND]: this.invokeSecondCall,
    [ButtonType.THIRD]: this.invokeThirdCall
  };

  clicked(resp: EventResponse) {
    this.lookEvents[resp.type](resp.event);
  }

  invokeFirstCall(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  invokeSecondCall(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  invokeThirdCall(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I think with this approach, it is possible to reduce `@Outputs` to a single one, but I will have to use switch-case in order to distinguish the button on the parrent. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, you will need to use the switch-case to distinguish the button in parent component.

Comment: In this case I think I have to convert it to a proper structure for Open/Closed of SOLID. Then, What do you think about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539793/open-closed-principle-in-angular/64540281#64540281) question?

Comment: Yes, instead of constant create a enum and if you want to avoid if-else then you can try lookups approach. Check the codesandbox sample. I have updated the code.

Comment: On the other hand, is it possible to apply open/closed principle to the code on that question except from using enum? Any idea? You can post your answers on that page.

Comment: That question is marked as closed so can't add there. However I guess lookup approach which I have used in above code will satisfy open/close principle.

Comment: Now it is opened :) Then you may add your answer